# Use drawable image stored in the app with gilde

Tags: android, drawable

I receive the image link from the API like:
"http://host/skin/images/answer_picture/image_1.png"

But i want to use the images directly from the app, because many user have problems loading the images.

So i added the images to the app and i change the API to get only the image name "image_1.png".

The old code was:

```
            View txtOption;

            if (AppConstant.arQuestionList.get(questionid).getArAnswer().get(i).getAtype()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
                txtOption = new ImageView(this);

                try {

                        Glide.with(QuestionActivity.this).load(AppConstant.arQuestionList.get(questionid)
                            .getArAnswer().get(i).getAnswer()).override(60, 60).into((ImageView)
                            txtOption); 

                }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                txtOption.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            } else {
                txtOption = new TextView(this);

                ((TextView) txtOption).setText(AppConstant.arQuestionList.get(questionid)
                        .getArAnswer().get
                                (i).getAnswer());
                ((TextView) txtOption).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.answer_color));
                ((TextView) txtOption).setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
                ((TextView) txtOption).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                txtOption.setPadding(10, 20, 10, 20);
            }
```

New code (not working):

```
                    // get the img name example: Skill_test.png
                    String imgName = AppConstant.arQuestionList.get(questionid)
                            .getArAnswer().get(i).getAnswer();

                    // delete image name extension 
                    if (imgName.endsWith(".png")) {
                        imgName = imgName.substring(0, imgName.length() - 5);
                    }

                    String uri = "drawable/"+imgName;


                   int idDrawable = getResources().getIdentifier(uri,"drawable", getPackageName());

                    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(QuestionActivity.this, idDrawable);

                    Glide.with(QuestionActivity.this)
                            .load("")
                            .placeholder(drawable)
                            .into((ImageView)txtOption);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what was the error

```
                    // get the img name, example: Skill_Hero_Skill-Name.png
                    String imgName = AppConstant.arQuestionList.get(questionid)
                            .getArAnswer().get(i).getAnswer();

                    // delete image name extension
                    if (imgName.endsWith(".png")) {
                        imgName = imgName.substring(0, imgName.length() - 4);
                    }

                    // string to lowercase
                    imgName = imgName.toLowerCase();

                    // replace "-" for "_"
                    imgName = imgName.replace('-','_');


                    String uri = "drawable/"+imgName.toLowerCase();

                    int imageResource  = getResources().getIdentifier(uri,"drawable", getPackageName());


                    Glide.with(QuestionActivity.this)
                            .load(imageResource)
                            .crossFade()
                            .override(60, 60)
                            .into((ImageView)txtOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
int idDrawable = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());

Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, idDrawable);

Glide.with(context)
         .load("")
         .placeholder(drawable)
         .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Sorry if the question is kind stupid.
getDrawable can't use context and imgName becuase can't read a string.
Also .into(txtOption) says "cannot resolve method 'into(androi.view.View).
I thinkg i'm doing everything wrong

Comment: Of course, you can't add an image in a TextView but you can in an ImageView. I edited my answer.

Comment: I tried with the new but still not workig, check what i do in the main question.